# Not call javascript function from vaadin 7

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin7

Vaadin 7

In my Vaadin app I want to call javascrtipt function  `onCustomName` and pass param:

```
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
String providerGUID = selectedProvider.getReference();
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().getJavaScript().execute("onCustomName(" + providerGUID + ")");
```

But nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCustomName` is not a built in JavaScript API in the Browser, so I assume you are using some JavaScript library in your application. You need to import it in the Java class using `@JavaScript` annotation. You probably need to do the call in `attach` event instead of constructor to ensure that call happens after library has been imported.